# Can't shut down or restart after 13.10 upgrade

Tags: reboot

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10, and when I try to shut down the system, by using the up-right button of the screen, nothing happens. I have to switch off the computer manualy. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try sutting down using a terminal (ctrl + alt + t) `sudo shutdown now`

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.

So to shutdown from terminal type: `sudo shutdown  -h now`
To reboot type: `sudo shutdown -r now`

Comment: if you don't have the scripts in /sbin/ .. then this doesn't work...